# How to create reference of an interface class through Reflection in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, reflection, repository

I'm using repository structure in my application.

I have a interface class **IDemoService**

```
public interface IDemoService
{
    bool CreateDemo(Demo demo);
    bool UpdateDemo(Demo demo);
    bool DeleteDemo(int id);
    Demo GetDemo(int id);
    Demo GetDemoServiceByName(string name);
    IEnumerable<Demo> GetAllDemo();
    void SaveRecord();
}
```

with ***using System.Reflection;*** I need to create reference like

```
IDemoService iDemoService;
```

I've tried this way so far:

```
var iDemoServiceClass = asm.GetTypes().Where(p =>
     p.Namespace == nameSpace &&
     p.Name == "IDemoService"
   ).ToList();
Type iDemoServiceClassType = iDemoServiceClass.FirstOrDefault();
var className = iDemoServiceClassType.Name;
var functionName = "Get" + iDemoServiceClassType + "ByName";
MethodInfo getMethod = demoServiceClassType.GetMethod(functionName);

var instanceCreate = Activator.CreateInstance(iDemoServiceClassType);//, null); //here I want to create reference instead instance
ParameterInfo[] parameters = getMethod.GetParameters();

if (parameters.Length > 0)
{
    object[] parametersArray = new object[] { "RequiredDemo" };
    var demoObj = getMethod.Invoke(instanceCreate, parametersArray);
}
```

Since it is interface so can't create instance but reference is possible. So, is it possible anyway to create reference using Reflection or any other way? 
Please help me right way. Thanks advance :D

Comment: A reference allways points to an instance of a class. You cannot "create a reference". Only create instances of a class that implement an interface.

Comment: is it impossible to create reference like IDemoService iDemoService; through reflection??? my question is here only

Comment: You allways need an instance to which a reference points. What should "create a reference" do? Point to nothing? There is no such thing as a reference that points to nothing, so a reference is allways related to an actual object of a class. You have to create an instance of a class that implements your interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an interface, and so you can't create a reference to it. You need a concrete type implementing that interface, than you can use `Activator.CreateInstance`.

The point is that an *interface* is just a contract, not a real implementation; so for example you have no method bodies. Imagine the compiler letting you activate the interface, what is supposed to happen when you call a method without a body?

At least you need an empty class in the form `DemoService:IDemoService`, than you get a reference to it.

Hope it helps.